# Capture the small arUco marker

Tags: java, android, opencv, aruco

I have a problem when I detect a small pixel (length and width both both are smaller than 0.4 cm) of aruco marker. Is there anyway to solve this problem by Android Java?

[Image of my aruco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpzKZ.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

It is not android or java problem. It is just how ArUco library works. While searching of markers it declines whose who are too small. Try to adjust `MarkerDetector::Params::_minSize` parameter.

Also, can you provide sample image? Once I had problem with very small marker which was caused by bad printer resolution - marker had visual defects, which affected their detection.

Comment: I had post the sample image of my aruco.

Comment: Marker looks normal and its size is ok. Have you tried to capture same marker of bigger size? Does it capture properly? Have you tried to vary `MarkerDetector::Params::_minSize` as I suggested?